# Should dependentSchemas property need to be added in additionalProperties

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am trying to write a schema, where if property A is present then property B or C should also per present using [dependencyschema](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html#dependentschemas) construct, and in my schema, I have turned off any additionalProperties.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
  "$id": "PropertiesSchema.json",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "A": { "type": "boolean" }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "dependentSchemas": {
    "A": {
      "anyOf": [
        { "required": [ "B" ] },
        { "required": [ "C" ] }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "B": { "type": "boolean" },
        "C": { "type": "boolean" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but it is currently failing for below input becuase of additionalProperties construct

{ "A": true, "B": false } or { "A": true, "C": false }

So is it possible that dependentSchemas properties are allowed when additionalProperties is turned off?

Thus valid input should be

{ "A": true, "B": false } or { "A": true, "C": false }

but for any other property say D, it should fail-

{ "A": true, "D": false }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`additionalProperties` can only take into account `properties` (and `patternProperties`) at the same schema object level.

If you change this to `unevaluatedProperties` you will find it working.

`unevaluatedProperties` can "see through" applicator keywords, such as `dependentSchemas`. It must wait for other keywords to be resolved first, and is resolved last.

Comment: worth noting: `additionalProperties` also takes into account properties matched by `patternProperties`.

Comment: I can see how it could have read. Thanks. Edited.